# Is there a way to set the first enum value to 1 in protobuf?

Tags: angular, protocol-buffers, primeng

The first enum value needs to be `0` in protobuf, but this does some trouble in a dropdown component of Primeng.

Is there a way to set the first enum value to `1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum), Protobuf is not allowed to set the first enum value to other value except 0:

> As you can see, the Corpus enum's first constant maps to zero: every enum definition must contain a constant that maps to zero as its first element. This is because:
>
> - There must be a zero value, so that we can use 0 as a numeric default value.
> - The zero value needs to be the first element, for compatibility with the proto2 semantics where the first enum value is always the default.

Comment: This is correct. I solved my problem by introducing a 'default' enum that gets filtered out when I fill the dropdown.